# inputAccessoryView disappears after presenting UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, xcode8, inputaccessoryview

I have a UICollectionViewController with an inputAccessoryView. Everything works great until I present a UIViewController, and then the accessory view disappears.  Trying to get basic Chat application features.

I have implemented in the collection view:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return inputContainerView
    }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

As suggested in multiple other threads, I also call (in the collection view),

```
view.resignFirstResponder()
view.inputAccessoryView?.reloadInputViews()
view.becomeFirstResponder()
```

after dismissing the UIViewController but to no avail.  print(view.isFirstResponder) still prints `false`.  I have tried almost every combination of the above three lines in numerous different places in my code.  I think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: interesting. I thought only textFields and textViews had an inputAccessoryView...anyhow: I think for the inputAccessoryView to be on the screen the view that it belongs to must be the current responder...but because you presented a viewControlle...it has been resigned and now you need to make its view become firstResponder again...I'm guessing a quick solution would be to put `view.becomeFirstResponder()` inside your `viewDidAppear` which insures the inputAccessoryView to be there everytime you come to the screen.

Comment: I found out here, skip to 15:00 if ur really interested:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky7YRh01by8   Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Did my suggestion work?!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not.... for some reason whenever I call becomeFirstResponder it never works

Comment: Update: a slight modification of your suggestion worked... I used `viewDidAppear` (which I have never used) to present the loginController and that worked.  I never had to call `view.becomeFirstResponder()`   My timer method below essentially accomplished the same thing, but this is much less hacky and professional.  Much appreciated.  I will remember this

Comment: What modification? I mentioned `viewDidAppear`...what did you change?

Comment: Instead of presenting the view controller in `viewDidLoad` I presented it in your suggested `viewDidAppear`.   When this view controller was presented from `viewDidLoad` it seemed to permanently remove the first responder property.  Calling `view.becomeFirstResponder` alone in `viewDidAppear` for some reason did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The animation to present and dismiss view controller might be causing issue or You haven't maintained a global ivar for the view you have setted as input accessory view. Try creating a readonly ivar for the accessoryview so only one instance is allocated and maintained through out VC life cycle. Then ensure to set it back to the textfields before calling reloadInputViews.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I up voted but I have less than 15 rep

Answer (score -1):

After a few days I finally figured out something that works... I think I was trying to present the loginController before the collectionView was set as the first responder.  Instead of just calling `present` I called this function:

```
func presentLoginControllerAfterImFirstResponder(fromUser: Bool) {
    // Starts a timer
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        // Is this view the first responder?
        if self.isFirstResponder {
            // Creates the loginController
            let loginController = LoginController()
            // Presents it
            self.present(loginController, animated: fromUser, completion: {
                // Once presented, sets rootViewController = self
                loginController.rootViewController = self
            })
            // Stop the timer
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

This works now.  I guess the collectionView needed some time to set itself as the first responder?  I can present and dismiss the loginController no problem and the inputAccessoryView remains.